# Deploy Rails docker container to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, heroku

Hello I tried some tutorial to deploy a rails container to heroku but I'm still asking me if that is possible cause it doesn't work
Thanks you for you help .

Comment: Voting down a new user? Come on guys.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, they even created a tutorial on how to do so:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime

and

https://blog.heroku.com/introducing_heroku_docker_release_build_deploy_heroku_apps_with_docker